# How does code Navigation in RStudio work?

Tags: r, rstudio

I'd like to follow child files (open them) in RMarkdown like the following by clicking with `CTRl+left click`.
Where can I find ressources to develop such a behavior?

````
```
{r, child=c("test.Rmd")}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use base for that

```
file.edit('test.Rmd')
```

If you mean you want to do this on a rendered document or on a notebook

```
Open the file at [Go to file](file.Rmd){target="_blank"}
```

Comment: that's a nice workaround but not as convenient as `CTRL+Click`, right?

Comment: you execute code with `ctrl+enter`, you do not follow a link/path

Comment: Maybe you need the file on the rendered document? I would suggest a notebook for that but I have provided a cheap alternative

Comment: thanks for your alternative but that's not what I was looking for.

Comment: I just saw your edited version. You may have misunderstood me. I am transitioning from TeXStudio to RStudio for writing documents. In TexStudio you can simply click on `test` within `\input{test}` and jump to the source file.

Comment: Never saw that in rstudio,don't really think it will happen on Rmd, Rmd wait for render time to create the links in Markdown format and the renders  Markdown on whatever extension you are after (pdf,html, etc.) It wasn't really designed for what you have in mind, maybe some people more experienced in it can solve this problem but the way you worded your question and the amount of time it has been left unanswered probably already killed it for SO, either way I am upvoting hopefully someone knows it, maybe you can show some screenshots of what TexStudio does next time?

Comment: said differently, I'd like to jump to the source file like jumping to the source file from an .R file by clicking on `source("test.Rmd")`.

Comment: I understand, I just don't think it is possible

Comment: thx for your comment and sorry for the confusing question!

Comment: At least not before rendering, after you render both you can then link one output with another rather easily you just can't get that before rendering

Comment: thanks for helping out! I'm reading now the source code of render ;) Maybe I can find a solution in there, but probably not, otherwise you could already do that :)